# removing /bin/sh from /etc/inititab

Tags: shell, bin

I study embedded linux.

By removing `/bin/sh` from `/etc/inittab`, I expect to prevent another user's shell usage.

I expected this right ?

And,

Others have a way to call back to the shell ?

Comment: That last question does not compute.